# toggle divs using a Bootstrap "nav", "data-toggle" and angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

So what I am trying to do is a form which is due to its length displayed over multiple pages. To realise this I am using different div's beeing displayed seperatly on one html page.

**I am using angularJS and Bootstrap with this little piece of code:**
It doesn't matter how I load this code. It's not working as first thing in a index.html file nor being loaded as a template with angularJS.

```
<div ng-controller="uploadCtrl">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" data-target="#part1">Start</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" data-target="#part2">Step 2</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" data-target="#part3">Finish</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="part1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                <h3>Form part 1</h3>
                <p>Some content.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="part2" class="tab-pane fade">
                <h3>Form part 2</h3>
                <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="part3" class="tab-pane fade">
                <h3>Form part 3</h3>
                <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

My **problem** is I can only click once on the links in the nav. There seems to be a problem with the toggle-function of `class="active"`. Clicking on a link adds the active-class but it is never removed.

After clicking on every link they all look like this: `<li><a data-toggle="tab" data-target="#part1" class="active" aria-expanded="true">Form part 1</a></li>`

Plus none of my `<li>` are of `class="active"` after the first link-selection.

---

I am only using

- jquery.min.js
- bootstrap.min.js
- bootstrap.min.css
- npm.min.js
- angular.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend you to use [angular-ui bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap) for this. It has a special case for nested forms. Using `bootstrap.js` over `angular` that already provides DOM manipulations is a bit redundant and can cause unexpected behaviour.

```
<form name="outerForm" class="tab-form-demo">
    <uib-tabset active="activeForm">
      <uib-tab index="0" heading="Form Tab">
        <ng-form name="nestedForm">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" required ng-model="model.name"/>
          </div>
        </ng-form>
      </uib-tab>
      <uib-tab index="1" heading="Tab One">
        Some Tab Content
      </uib-tab>
      <uib-tab index="2" heading="Tab Two">
        More Tab Content
      </uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>
  </form>
```

More info [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs)

Comment: Thanks this seems like the right thing to look for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be something wrong with my libraries.

I switched to Bootstrap **Version 3.3.6** and it worked perfectly. Earlier I used the current **Version 4.0.0** from Bootstraps Homepage given through the standard download option.